# Next.JS with cloudinary dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, next.js, url-routing, nextjs-dynamic-routing, dynamic-routing

### Error

- Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, path}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

### Explanation

I'm new to next.js and want to create an application using Cloudinary. The website is for an event company that has different folders for events that I have placed inside of cloudinary that have titles corresponding to the event. I'm trying to fetch the array of folders and map through them dynamically. I'm using a [slug].js

#### pages->index.jsx

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
    search,
    mapImageResources,
    fetchCloudinaryFolders,
    getFolders, // Import the new fetchCloudinaryFolders function
} from "../lib/cloudinary";

import styles from "../styles/Home.module.scss";

export default function Home({
    images: defaultImages,
    nextCursor: defaultNextCursor,
    totalCount: defaultTotalCount,
    folders,
    cloudinaryFolders,
}) {
    const [images, setImages] = useState(defaultImages);
    const [nextCursor, setNextCursor] = useState(defaultNextCursor);
    const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState(defaultTotalCount);
    const [activeFolder, setActiveFolder] = useState();
    const router = useRouter();

    async function handleOnLoadMore(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const results = await search({ expression: `folder=""`, nextCursor }); 

        const {
            resources,
            next_cursor: nextPageCursor,
            total_count: updatedTotalCount,
        } = results;

        const newImages = mapImageResources(resources);

        setImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, ...newImages]);
        setNextCursor(nextPageCursor);
        setTotalCount(updatedTotalCount);
    }

    function handleOnFolderClick(e) {
        const folderPath = e.target.dataset.folderPath;

        router.push(`/folder/${folderPath}`);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const results = await search({
                    expression: `folder="${activeFolder || ""}"`,
                });

                const {
                    resources,
                    next_cursor: nextPageCursor,
                    total_count: updatedTotalCount,
                } = results;

                const newImages = mapImageResources(resources);

                setImages(newImages);
                setNextCursor(nextPageCursor);
                setTotalCount(updatedTotalCount);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
            }
        }

        if (activeFolder) {
            fetchData();
        }
    }, [activeFolder]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function run() {
            const results = await search({
                expression: `folder="${activeFolder || ""}"`,
            });

            const {
                resources,
                next_cursor: nextPageCursor,
                total_count: updatedTotalCount,
            } = results;

            const newImages = mapImageResources(resources);

            setImages(newImages);
            setNextCursor(nextPageCursor);
            setTotalCount(updatedTotalCount);
        }

        run();
    }, [activeFolder]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchFolders() {
            try {
                const folders = await fetchCloudinaryFolders();
                setCloudinaryFolders(folders);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching Cloudinary folders:", error);
            }
        }

        fetchFolders();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Cloudinary Folders</h1>
            <ul>
                {cloudinaryFolders.map((folderName) => (
                    <li key={folderName}>
                        <Link href={`/cloudinary/${folderName}`}>
                            <div>{folderName}</div>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <h1 className='sr-only text-white'>My Images</h1>

            <h2 className='text-white'>Folders</h2>

            {folders && folders.length > 0 && (
                <ul className={styles.folders} onClick={handleOnFolderClick}>
                    {folders.map((folder) => {
                        const isActive = folder.path === activeFolder;
                        return (
                            <li key={folder.path} data-active-folder={isActive}>
                                <button data-folder-path={folder.path}>{folder.name}</button>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            )}

            <h2 className='text-white'>Images</h2>
            {totalCount > images.length && (
                <p className='text-white'>
                    <button className='text-white' onClick={handleOnLoadMore}>
                        Load More Results
                    </button>
                </p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const results = await search();

    const { resources, next_cursor: nextCursor } = results;

    const images = mapImageResources(resources);

    let folders = []; // Initialize folders as an empty array

    try {
        const response = await getFolders(); // Use your getFolders function here
        folders = response || []; // If response is undefined, set folders to an empty array
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching folders:", error);
    }

    let cloudinaryFolders = [];
    try {
        const response = await fetchCloudinaryFolders();
        cloudinaryFolders = response || []; // If response is undefined, set cloudinaryFolders to an empty array
    
        console.log("folders:", folders);


    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching Cloudinary folders:", error);
    }

    return {
        props: {
            images,
            nextCursor,
            folders, // Use the folders variable here
            totalCount: images.length,
            folders, // Use the folders variable here
            cloudinaryFolders,
        },
    };
}
```

#### Pages->Folder->[Slug].js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { searchByFolder } from '../../lib/cloudinary'; 
import Folder from '../../components/Folder';

const CloudinaryFolder = ({ folderSlug, data }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Use the folderSlug to fetch resources from Cloudinary
    searchByFolder(folderSlug).then((results) => {
    
    });
  }, [folderSlug]);

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  // Map over the 'data' object and render each item
  const renderedData = Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
    <div key={key}>
      {/* Render individual data properties */}
      {data[key].name} - {data[key].path}
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render the mapped data */}
      {renderedData}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params;

  // Fetch Cloudinary data using searchByFolder function
  const data = await searchByFolder(slug);

  // Check if data is valid and not empty
  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  // Pass the data as a prop 
  return {
    props: {
      folderSlug: slug,
      data: data, 
    },
  };
}

export default CloudinaryFolder;
```

#### lib->cloudinary.js

```
export async function fetchCloudinaryFolders() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/folders`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY + ':' + process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET).toString('base64')}`,
      },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.folders; // Assuming data is an array of folder names
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching Cloudinary folders:', error);
    return []; // Return an empty array in case of an error
  }
}

export async function search(options = {}) {
  const params = {
    ...options
  }

  if (options.nextCursor) {
    params.next_cursor = options.nextCursor;
    delete params.nextCursor;
  }

  const paramString = Object.keys(params).map(key => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`).join('&');

  const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/resources/search?${paramString}`;

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY + ':' + process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET).toString('base64')}`,
  };

  const results = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  }).then(r => r.json());

  return results;
}

export function mapImageResources(resources) {
  if (!resources || !Array.isArray(resources.resources)) {
    // Handle the case where resources or resources.resources is undefined or not an array
    return [];
  }

  return resources.resources.map(resource => {
    const { width, height } = resource;
    return {
      id: resource.asset_id,
      title: resource.public_id,
      image: resource.secure_url,
      width,
      height
    }
  });
}


export async function getFolders(options = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/folders`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY + ':' + process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET).toString('base64')}`
    }
  }).then(r => r.json());

  return response.folders;
}

export async function searchByFolder(folderName, options = {}) {
  const params = {
    ...options
  }

  if (options.nextCursor) {
    params.next_cursor = options.nextCursor;
    delete params.nextCursor;
  }

  const paramString = Object.keys(params).map(key => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`).join('&');

  const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/resources/search?folder=${encodeURIComponent(folderName)}&${paramString}`;

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY + ':' + process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET).toString('base64')}`,
  };

  const results = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  }).then((r) => r.json());

  return results;
}
```

#### pages->api->search.js

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { body } = req;

  try {
    const params = JSON.parse(body);

    const results = await search(params);

    res.status(200).json({ ...results });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in search handler:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while processing your request.' });
  }
}
```

Here is the error I keep getting. Which I understand is probably an easy fix but I'm new and cannot figure it out. - error Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, path}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are, as the error clearly states trying to render an  object with the keys `name` and `path`. Object are not valid react children. Check your JSX and log the variables that you inject into it.